# Creating a new component with Castle Windsor providing the DI

Tags: castle-windsor

I'm new to Windsor and am trying to get my head around how to do this in a standalone client (WPF in my case).

I have a class called a `PictureWrapper` that uses a `PictureClient`, like this:

```
public class PictureWrapper
{
  private PictureClient myClient;
  public PictureWrapper(int clientID)
  {
    myClient = new PictureClient();
    //etc
  } 
}
```

In my PictureWrapper project, I can create a WindsorInstaller class that looks like this:

```
    public class WindsorInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Component.For<IPictureClient>().ImplementedBy<PictureClient>().LifestyleTransient());
    }
}
```

Assuming I call the `Install()` method above beforehand, here's where I get a little lost-- how exactly do I now create the `PictureWrapper` class in my WPF application?  Do I still new() it up?

And given I'm not passing an instance of the `PictureClient` class in the `PictureWrapper`'s constructor, how do I initialize it when creating the `PictureWrapper`?

I could, I suppose, make it a constructor parameter but when I create the `PictureWrapper` in the client, what do I pass to its constructor in my client?  I'm trying to figure out how to get the DI ball rolling from my client, essentially.

Comment: Try reading some introductory material on DI and Castle Windsor. The WIKI is probably a good starting point. http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.MainPage.ashx Make sure you understand the basic concepts.

Comment: What @PhilDegenhardt says can't be stressed enough. We could give you the correct configuration directly but you wouldn't be able to tweak it afterwards. I recommend reading up, trying some first tests and if you fail asking a question with the problem you are encountering

Comment: I get the bits about installing and registering components.  The problem is (for me, anyway) is I don't use ASP.Net MVC and that appears to be where most of the interest in using Windsor lies, and where the tutorials are focused.
In my case, a non-MVC project, is it really just a matter of calling `container.Resolve<IMyInterface>()` when I want to use a new object?  (Assuming no fancy constructor parameters).  Is `Resolve` what I should be doing as a matter of course?  Is that considered ok Windsor practice?

Comment: The MVC topic gets a lot of coverage because MVC has a few dangerous roads people can go down and get themselves into trouble. Windsor works great in all types of apps. Yes you can simply call container.Resolve<>(). But the secret to real success with Windsor is to minimise the points in your application that even know the container exists - hopefully just one object, sometimes called the composition root. And ALWAYS make sure you have a matching Release() for every Resolve()... http://kozmic.net/2010/08/27/must-i-release-everything-when-using-windsor/